# Can gravitational waves cause a large asymmetric planet to spin?

Tags: solar-system, gravitational-waves

As planets orbit Earth it won't be perfectly spherical because of gravity But can gravitational waves make the asymmetrical Earth spin a little?

Comment: Planets don't orbit Earth.  They orbit the sun.  How much of "a little" are you willing to accept.  Would a surface motion of 1mm in a billion billion years be "spin a little"?

Comment: @DAveTheWave.  There is a difference between not being perfectly spherical and being asymmetric.  For many purposes Earth is an oblate spheroid  and so is symmetrical.  It takes a really close examination to notice Earth's minor asymmetric deviations from the figure of an oblate spheroid.  And of course mountains and valleys, continents and ocean basins make Earth slightly asymmetric.

Comment: Any effect would be tiny.  GW have very weak coupling to matter, so any transference of momentum or torque from the wave would be entirely neglible.  It would have far less effect than the proverbial girl spinning anticlockwise to make the night last longer.

Comment: potentially helpful [Do gravitational waves impart linear momentum to objects? (e.g. Quasar 3C 186)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321166/83380)